# Adding Information windows on top of a map view marker not same in different dpis

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers

I'm using this code to add a layout that presents my information about a marker on top of the marker. While i used codes to convert pixels to dpi in this code. but it don't look in different dpis same view.

```
 protected override bool OnTap (int index)
    {
        if (!ShowPropertyFlag) {
            if (mapview .ChildCount > 0) {
                mapview .RemoveViewAt (0);
            }
            if (_items [index].Snippet == Boolean .FalseString) {
                InformationLayout iWindow = new InformationLayout 
            (mapview .Context, _Properties [_items [index].Title], sayActivity);

                GeoPoint p = _items [index].Point;

                MapView.LayoutParams _params = new MapView.LayoutParams
            (WindowManagerLayoutParams .WrapContent,
                   WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent 
                     , p,-(int) Common .convertPixelsToDp    (13,sayActivity ),-(int) Common .convertPixelsToDp  (25,sayActivity ), 
                     MapView .LayoutParams .Bottom   );
                _params.Mode = MapView .LayoutParams .ModeMap;

                iWindow .Visibility = ViewStates .Visible;

                mapview .AddView (iWindow, _params);
                mapview .HasIWindows =true ;

            } else {
                Property[] m = _SubProperties [_items [index].Title];
                List <Property > templist= m.OfType <Property > () .ToList ();
                sayActivity .ListShow (templist ,m.Length );
            }

        }
            return base.OnTap (index);

    }
```

and this is the code that i use in`Common .convertPixelsToDp` for converting Pixel to Dp

```
    public static float convertPixelsToDp (float px, Context context)
    {
        return  px / ((float)context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi / 160f);
    }
```

my markers width x height is: 25 x 45

Because I'm a new user i can't post images of my information windows and marker in different dpis.But i explain it. in ldpi it seems good and is in good possion(I fix it by trying diffrent numbers and finaly by 13 and 25 it get fixed) but in hdpi the information windows look about center of marker instead of top of marker.I don't understand why?While i used pixel to dp converter.

Edit:

Maybe the links help to see images in differnt dpis:

hdpi: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8vjO.png

ldpi: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLH5o.png

Comment: I think it should have some wrong about layout parameters parameters or parameters mode. have any body ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using `OverlayItems`?

Comment: This is in and overlayItem Class

Comment: OK, it was not at all clear from your question. The context is entirely off for me.

Comment: the content of the information layout have to change in run time based on marker location.Therefore it have to be a view that its content can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the link:

[MapView.LayoutParams](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.LayoutParams#MapView.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

the x and y offsets in mapview.layoutparams have to send based on px.
It means that if you even convert it to dp, the consructor also assume it a px.
Therefore the best way is using form Height of the marker.
The code resolve the problem.(`location_Marker` is the marker that shows in the map):

```
MapView.LayoutParams _params = new MapView.LayoutParams
                    ( MapView .LayoutParams  .WrapContent,
                     MapView .LayoutParams  .WrapContent 
                     , p,0,
                     - sayActivity .Resources .GetDrawable (Resource .Drawable .location_Marker ).IntrinsicHeight , 
                     MapView .LayoutParams .Bottom   );
```